# VBA: Add multiple same size ranges in a cumulative way

Tags: excel, vba

So I have multiple columns of the same size and equally spaced, which I want to add altogether in the first two columns of the sheet.

```
Sub flujos_SPC()

    Dim spcode As Range
    Dim codigos As Worksheet: Set codigos = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mp pruebas")
    Set spcode = codigos.Range("F6", codigos.Range("F6").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim remat As Worksheet: Set remat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("r.matem (2)")
    Dim destino As Worksheet: Set destino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flujos por SPC")
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim col As Integer: col = 5
    Dim contador As Integer: spcode.Count
    
    For Each cell In spcode
        remat.Range("I3") = cell.Value
        With destino
            .Cells(1, col) = "SP Code"
            .Cells(2, col) = cell.Value
            .Range(.Cells(1, col + 1), .Cells(1225, col + 2)) = remat.Range("Q11", "R1235").Value
     
        End With
        col = col + 4
    Next cell
   
End Sub
```

The columns are generated as such and they all have numeric values, positive non integers for the most part.
I thought about adding the ranges the same way you add to the same variable (x = x + 1), but I get mismatch type errors.
Ideally, what I would like to do would be to embbed a cumulative sum inside the for each loop, such as:

```
Sub flujos_SPC()

    Dim spcode As Range
    Dim codigos As Worksheet: Set codigos = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("mp pruebas")
    Set spcode = codigos.Range("F6", codigos.Range("F6").End(xlDown))
    
    Dim remat As Worksheet: Set remat = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("r.matem (2)")
    Dim destino As Worksheet: Set destino = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Flujos por SPC")
    Dim cell As Range
    
    Dim col As Integer: col = 5
    Dim contador As Integer: spcode.Count
    
    destino.range("A2","B1225") = 0
    For Each cell In spcode
        remat.Range("I3") = cell.Value
        With destino
            .Cells(1, col) = "SP Code"
            .Cells(2, col) = cell.Value
            .Range(.Cells(1, col + 1), .Cells(1225, col + 2)) = remat.Range("Q11", "R1235").Value
     
            .range("A2","B1225") = .range("A2","B1225") + .Range(.Cells(1, col + 1), .Cells(1225, col + 2))
        End With
        col = col + 4
    Next cell
   
End Sub
```

But then again, I get errors when trying this, even when adding ".value" to each range. I would like some help with this and preferably avoid the use of for loops, mostly for performance reasons. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Range("A2","B1225")` in a Let statement is accessing its default member which is `.Value`. The `Value` property of a multi-cell `Range` is a 2D array of Variants. You cannot use Arrays with operators in VBA. `+` and `-` will give mismatch type errors because they are looking for a single value but you are providing an array.

Comment: So I have to use a loop then?

Comment: Yes, unfortunately, anytime you work with arrays in VBA, you can't avoid looping. But if you have concerns about performance, you should take the Range Values into an array, complete the sums in the array and then paste the values back into the sheet. This will be a surprisingly large amount faster than adding the values in the sheet. And VBA makes it easy to move between ranges and arrays: `MyArr = Range.Value` fills the array in one line. `Range.Value = MyArr` puts each array value into the corresponding cell. Very intuitive!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could build a formulaR1C1 string.

```vb
    Dim f as String
    For Each cell In spcode
        f = f + "+RC[" & col & "]"
        remat.Range("I3") = cell.Value
        With destino
            .Cells(1, col) = "SP Code"
            .Cells(2, col) = cell.Value
            .Range(.Cells(1, col + 1), .Cells(1225, col + 2)) = remat.Range("Q11", "R1235").Value
        End With
        col = col + 4
    Next cell
    destino.Range("A2", "B1225").FormulaR1C1 = "=" & f
```

Comment: This is very useful, I'm gonna test it to see if its faster to use this or to use an array inside the for loop.